# How to create a query that takes long time to run in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

To test my application I need a query to run for a long time (at least a couple of minutes). Any ideas on how to create this quickly?

The application needs to query the catalog to see a list of running queries.

My application uses postgresql. I am fine with creating additional dummy tables if required.

Comment: No indexes, LIKE, etc.

Comment: lot of  of inner  join ..

Comment: `do $$ begin while true loop end loop; end $$`

Comment: Thanks you jarlh, Matt, scaisEdge. I created a small table with 2 million rows then ran a query with an inner join and couple of LIKE's. This query is taking quite a long time, which is what I wanted.

Comment: @Silvermind, I need to query catalog to get a list of currently active queries.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

this will run for 5 minutes:

```
select pg_sleep(5 * 60);
```

the parameter for `pg_sleep()` is the duration in seconds.

You can also sleep until a specific timestamp using `pg_sleep_until()`

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-DELAY

Comment: This is great! Exactly what I needed. Not having to create dummy data makes this a really elegant solution.

Comment: How to combine this with existing query? Like if I already have `select * from users where id=10`?