# PostgreSQL: how to simulate long running query

Tags: postgresql

I need to simulate a long-running Connection to PostgreSQL (f.e. 60 seconds) to verify my application can handle it.
I believe that by adding a few millions rows to a Table would work, however I'd need a more deterministic approach, such as a PostgreSQL Procedure with a function or a loop. That would not require to fill tables at first and empty them at the end of the test.
Can you recommend anything that would work for my case?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a query that takes long time to run in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35336262/how-to-create-a-query-that-takes-long-time-to-run-in-postgresql) and (related) [Delay or Wait-For Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331409/delay-or-wait-for-statement)

Comment: [Use `pg_sleep`](https://database.guide/how-pg_sleep-works-in-postgresql/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's exactly what I was looking for.